# Best cluster configuration for Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I currently have a 2 node DS2.Large Redshift Cluster. We are excepting heavy rise in both computation(complex as well as frequent queries) as well as storage( not as important, archiving is an option). What would be the best configuration, a 32 node DC2.Large cluster or a 2 node DC2.8XLarge cluster?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience always go with a larger number of smaller resources. It will add more resiliency if you do not want to lose 50% of your capacity.

Comment: Thanks. Though, DC2.xlarge clusters max out at 32 nodes, hence I lose all possiblity of scaling further.

Comment: Once you warrant then scale upto a DC2.8xlarge. You are able to change the number of nodes and type: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-cluster-operations.html

Comment: Thanks, though thats a classic resize, with added downtime. I just want to understand what benefits do I get in choosing more smaller nodes over less bigger nodes.

Comment: Should be able to do this with an elastic resize, it just puts it into readonly mode whilst it occurs

Comment: Personally I would try both and benchmark with real queries to see which gives you the best performance.